# Ignore all .cpp file in Flutter repository

Tags: github, gitignore

Every time I create Flutter public repository, the languages ​​highlighted by github are c++ files and make the dart files contained in the repository blocked.
Are there some c++ file that i can put in gitignore safely?
Is it safe to ignore all .cpp or .cc file in my flutter repositories?

I have to write a lot of dart files to be highlighted and dominated on the languages ​​bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `.gitattributes` file to [override the language(s) detected by GitHub](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/c1c34e5260797b4d598f5ec76f19723bfc5a1894/docs/overrides.md)

```
# Do not detect
*.cc -linguist-detectable
*.cpp -linguist-detectable

# Detect
*.dart linguist-detectable
```

That way, the language bar will list and reflect only dart source files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding .gitattributes file didn't work either.
Finally I became to overcome this issue by **deleting 'linux', 'macos' and 'windows' folder.**
Further if you look into that 'linux' folder there are 'main.cc' and 'myapplication.cc' they are the main reason behind wrong linguist detection of Github.